# Personalizar la imagen de la agrupación de puntos en Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Para agrupar los puntos sobre un mapa de Google Maps utilizo la librería [map utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

Me gustaría personalizar la agrupación de puntos `MarkerClusterer`

Más o menos como la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para la imágen he encontrado ese .svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
    <defs>
        <g id="a" transform="rotate(45)">
            <path d="M0 47A47 47 0 0 0 47 0L62 0A62 62 0 0 1 0 62Z" fill-opacity="0.7"/>
            <path d="M0 67A67 67 0 0 0 67 0L81 0A81 81 0 0 1 0 81Z" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
            <path d="M0 86A86 86 0 0 0 86 0L100 0A100 100 0 0 1 0 100Z" fill-opacity="0.3"/>
        </g>
    </defs>
    <g fill="#004b7a ">
        <circle r="42"/>
        <g>
            <use xlink:href="#a"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(120)">
            <use xlink:href="#a"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(240)">
            <use xlink:href="#a"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Para personalizar la agrupación se debe crear una clase que extienda de `DefaultClusterRenderer`

```
public class MyClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    private final IconGenerator mClusterIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getApplicationContext());

    public MyClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                             ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item,
                                               MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

        BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA);

        markerOptions.icon(markerDescriptor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyItem> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions){

        final Drawable clusterIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        clusterIcon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_light), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(clusterIcon);

        //modify padding for one or two digit numbers
        if (cluster.getSize() < 10) {
            mClusterIconGenerator.setContentPadding(40, 20, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            mClusterIconGenerator.setContentPadding(30, 20, 0, 0);
        }

        Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
    }
}
```

Para personalizar el marcador individual

`BitmapDescriptor markerDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA);`

y para el fondo en `onBeforeClusterRendered` se debe ir ajustando los valores para obtener el resultado ajustado